# In Sql Server 2005, is there a way to query the total disk space (physical hard drive(s)) available on the server?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I found this in googling, but I don't think it's the complete code?

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_server_2005_windows_script_display_disk_space_usage.htm

I was hoping there was a simple system stored procedure, like for finding the total size of MDF file (exec sp_helpdb DATABASE_NAME).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Does xp_fixeddrives do the trick?

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_fixeddrives
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CLR stored procedure like this :

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/tarad/archive/2007/12/18/60435.aspx